# devise how to prevent a user from login in if account has not been activated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple rails application that uses devise authentication and I want to prevent a user from login in or requesting for password request or any thing that can grant access to a registered user.

In my user model I have a boolean field that helps me easily determine if the account has been activated or not, the boolean field is called active.

What call back methods can I use to go around this and to check if the user has been activated of not with devise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how you can set your `active` boolean after a confirmation email, you can override the `confirm!` method devise gives.

If you need a method to prevent a non active user to login etc., override the `new` method in the SessionsController.